# How can I make two constructors for a class, both having string, string but where they have a different purpose?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I have a class that is constructed in two different ways. One uses a text value and the other a binding. The problem I face is that both are represented by string, string.

My code has this:

```
new ValueGrid("Name", nameof(_vm.Name)) or
new ValueGrid("Name", "Name")
```

I would like to be

```
new ValueGrid("Name", "John")
```

In the case of the first example I can code a constructor like this:

```
public ValueGrid(string Text1, string Text2) : this()
{
   this.Text1 = Text1;
   this.SetBinding(ValueGrid.Text2Property, new Binding(Text2));
}
```

In the case of the second example I can code a constructor like this:

```
public ValueGrid(string Text1, string Text2) : this()
{
   this.Text1 = Text1;
   this.Text2 = Text2;
}
```

My problem is that both constructors although they act different are made up of a string followed by a string.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your title question: You can't.

Looking at the example I think it would be better to pass the binding class in the first example, and that will achieve the required result.

```
public ValueGrid(string Text1, Binding toBind) : this()
{
   this.Text1 = Text1;
   this.SetBinding(ValueGrid.Text2Property, toBind);
}

// usage: 
new ValueGrid("Name", new Binding(nameof(_vm.Name)))
```

And the second example will have the `string, string` constructor:

```
public ValueGrid(string Text1, string Text2) : this()
{
   this.Text1 = Text1;
   this.Text2 = Text2;
}

// usage: 
new ValueGrid("Name", "John")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use factory methods, which can named differently. You'd have one private parameterless constructor:

```
private ValueGrid() {}
```

And two factory methods:

```
public static ValueGrid FromText(string Text1, string Text2)
{
    var valueGrid = new ValueGrid {
        Text1 = Text1,
        Text2 = Text2
    };
    return valueGrid;
}

public static ValueGrid FromBinding(string Text1, string Text2)
{
    var valueGrid = new ValueGrid {
        Text1 = Text1
    };
    valueGrid.SetBinding(ValueGrid.Text2Property, new Binding(Text2));
    return valueGrid;
}
```

Comment: How would I call the two methods?

Comment: @RichardS Their names would be based on what the second parameter represents, like `FromBinding` and `FronText` as I showed. You could also add in the meaning of the first parameter too.